# RegEx to check 24 hours time format fails

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx that is supposed to do 24 hours time format validation, which I'm trying out in https://rubular.com

```
/^[0-23]{2}:[0-59]{2}:[0-59]{2}$/
```

But the following times fails to match even if they look correct

```
02:06:00
04:05:00
```

Why this is so?

Comment: `[0-23]` this is matching 0 to 2, and 3 (so 0, 1, 2, and 3). Regex does not do number comparison, only character.

Comment: .`[0-59]` matches 0,1,2,3,4,5 and 9

Comment: @Seblor Thanks for the hint, but shouldn't it take as a range as it's enclosed within `[ ]`?

Comment: No. Regex will see `23` as 2 text characters, not a single number.

Comment: Ok Thank You. That's a new learning.

Comment: There is literally no math in regular expressions, except for the quantifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In character classes, you're supposed to denote the *range of characters* allowed (in contrast to the numbers you want to match in your example). For minutes and seconds, this is relatively straight-forward - the following expression

```
[0-5][0-9]
```

...will match any numerical string from "00" to "59".

But for the hours, you need to two separate expressions:

```
[01][0-9]|2[0-3]
```

...one to match "00" to "19" and one to match "20" to "23". Due to the alternative used (`|` character), these need to be grouped, which adds another bit of syntax `(?:...)`. Finally we're just adding the anchors `^` and `$` for beginning and end of string, which you already had where they belong.

```
^(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$
```

You can check this [solution out at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/8VDuMB/1), if you like.

Comment: Thanks! I have figured out the regex. I'm using `^([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you understand characters ranges wrong: `0-23` doesn't mean "match any number from 0 to 23", it means: `0-2`- match one digit: 0,1 or 2, then match 3.

Try this pattern: `(?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3])(?::[0-5][0-9]){2}`

Explanation:

`(?:...)` - non-capturing group

`[01][0-9]|2[0-3]` - alternation: match whether 0 or one followed by any digits fro 0 to 9 **OR** 2 followed by 0, 1, 2 or 3 (number from 00-23)

`(?::[0-5][0-9]){2}` - match `:` and `[0-5][0-9]` (basically number from 00-59) twice

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/g1nR8C/1)

Answer (score 1):

use this `(([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])):(([0-5][0-9])):(([0-5][0-9]))`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/DrZ2vK/3/)

Comment: What about `23:00:00`?